# How can I Receive GCM/FCM Notification in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am new to Google Cloud. I have created a push Message service by using Google Cloud Messaging.

It's working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

I am using service-worker to receive notification, which is available in Google Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

How can I send push notification in IE?

Comment: I have the same problem... what you did ?

Comment: @user2503775 Finally we went with https://www.asp.net/signalr  for push notification

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't support the Web Push standard at the moment: https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#push.
Looks like it is in development for Edge.

Comment: Looking at the spec for this feature now, it might be possible to write a polyfill.

Comment: I think it's impossible. How would you implement receiving notifications while your site is not open?

Comment: I realized this about 5 mins after posting my comment. =(